# How to update field value in collection using angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I have above collection with three objects with fields named as Id & Name. I need to update Name field value as 'AAA' instead of 'ZZZ' at id=3 without using for-loop condition in angular.

```
function get()
{        
        var colls =[];        
        colls.push({id: 1, Name: 'XXX'});
        colls.push({id: 2, Name: 'YYY'});
        colls.push({id: 3, Name: 'ZZZ'});  
}
```

Thanks in advance
Dinesh

Comment: will you know always the position of *itemToUpdate* in collection? 
If **YES** you can access the item directly at position (without looping)   
If **NO**, you should iterate and find the item which must be updated